# Objective c - Combination of UIActivityViewController and navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using navigation bar, i'm changing the the default back button to my button in the viewDidLoad using the code:

```
_backButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
[_backButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[_backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back-icon.png"]];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _backButton;
```

And I have a UIButton for share, when I clicking on it, this code is running:

```
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"test"]
                                      applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:^{ 
}];
```

Now, when I enterd to the page it's look OK, but when I clicked on the share button, the UIActivityViewController is present, and the back button in the navigation, jump 50 pixels to the bottom - like in this image
[image]

When I use the default back button, it's not append.

I try to change the animated of the  UIActivityViewController opening to NO and it didn't help.

What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: You are presenting view controller. That is for modal view. If you need that navigation bar is automatically set correct, use push for navigation stack.

Comment: I want to open it as modal, it need to open UIActivityViewController as it should be. and it's open it correct

Comment: When you present view controller, it does not use any navigation controller, so it does not have navigation bar. You need to add navigation bar by yourself via storyboard or xib. You need to add it as a subview of your view and set the frame and constraints if you are using  auto layout. If you want to present it modal with navigation function you need to present modal navigation controller that contains your ActivityViewController.

Comment: HI @Flipper, I don't understand what you are talking about, I'm using it to present UIActivityViewController, like in this article http://www.codingexplorer.com/add-sharing-to-your-app-via-uiactivityviewcontroller/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your back button as :

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_arrow"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)];
```

No need to create back button method, if you do not update any object value or any UI when going to previous controller.
And If you set any action to selector then use respective target.

And when you present ActivityController :

```
- (IBAction)commonSharing:(id)sender
{
    NSString *strTextToShare = @"Hi... Friends";
    UIImage *imgToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wall1.png"];
    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.apple.com"];

    UIActivityViewController *shareController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[strTextToShare, imgToShare, urlToShare] applicationActivities :nil];
    //shareController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]; // If you want to restrict some of apps to sharing
    [self presentViewController:shareController animated: YES completion: nil];
```

}

Comment: I need to save the button in the property _backButton, so I use this code, base on your code, and it help, thanks:     _backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyInventory-Back-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
    [_backButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = _backButton;